# Spring Boot Actuator - purpose of enable and expose endpoints

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

From [Spring Boot Actuator documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.endpoints)

> You can enable or disable each individual endpoint and expose them (make them remotely accessible) over HTTP or JMX. An endpoint is considered to be available when it is both enabled and exposed.

I don't understand why there is two features `enable` and `expose`

`management.endpoint.health.enabled=true`
`management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health`

From my point of view, the `expose` feature would be enough. Why is there another property to enable it ? 
I don't see any situation where we would like to enable an endpoint without exposing it over http or jmx.

Comment: you have an option to expose it over JMX and not over HTTP or both.

Comment: I know. What is the need for the `enable` option ? The `expose` option is enough, if I don't expose it over JMX or HTTP, the endpoint doesn't need to be registered.

Answer (score 3):

I might be wrong and probably only the people who designed this feature will know for sure, but in my understanding:

An **Enabled** endpoint means that the bean that represents this endpoint is up-and-running.

An **Exposed** endpoint means that its also available by JMX/HTTP (of course, it can be separated for more fine-grained control).

Obviously you can't keep anything "exposed" without being "enabled", however sometimes it might make sense to enable an endpoint but not expose it.

Namely, I can think of (in theory) about the need to access the "enabled" but not "exposed" endpoint programmatically from your application.
For example, if you want to have a bean in memory but instead of exposing it via HTTP/JMX - inject it into your own code to process it somehow.
Of maybe you want to expose it via some other way (custom UI, send the data periodically to some messaging system and what not). In this case you also will want to enable the feature but write your own exposure logic and disable the default exposure mechanisms for security reasons.

Having said that, I've never seen any actual requirement for all the above :)

Comment: you might be right, in some rare situation you could want to use the bean without exposing it. I will see if any spring boot developer see my question and confirm this assumption.